# NLS_SORT NLS_COMP read incorreclty

Tags: oracle, environment-variables, nls

I set NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP in hibernate:

```
Hibernate: ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=BINARY
Hibernate: ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY
```

After that i try to read it back using:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter in('NLS_SORT','NLS_COMP');
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'NLS_SORT') FROM DUAL;
```

This queries return incorrect values:

```
PARAMETER                      VALUE                                   
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_SORT                       RUSSIAN                                 
NLS_COMP                       BINARY                                  

2 rows selected.

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','NLS_SORT')                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RUSSIAN                                                                         
1 row selected.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no parameter for `NLS_COMP` in the `SYS_CONTEXT` function

Verified with

**NLS_CALENDAR** The current calendar of the current session.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_CALENDAR') FROM DUAL;
```

**NLS_CURRENCY** The currency of the current session.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_CURRENCY') FROM DUAL;
```

**NLS_DATE_FORMAT** The date format for the session.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT') FROM DUAL;
```

**NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE** The language used for expressing dates.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE') FROM DUAL;
```

**NLS_SORT** BINARY or the linguistic sort basis.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_SORT') FROM DUAL;
```

**NLS_TERRITORY** The territory of the current session.

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'NLS_TERRITORY') FROM DUAL;
```